# Sahara fail while trying to flash a rom into my phone

Tags: rom-flashing, rom

I tried to flash a custom rom into my phone but it was an unsuccessful try and I decided to update the TWRP recovery in order to increase my chances to flash a rom. But istead of updating TWRP I bricked my phone somehow I even don't understand. The phone is **Lenovo ZUK Z2**. I tried to flash a stock rom via QFIL previously installing all drivers needed.

But when I actually press the download button it says:

```
Validating Application Configuration
Load APP Configuration
COM:20
SAHARA:True
SAHARA:C:\ZUI\prog_emmc_firehose_8996_ddr.elf
SEARCHPATH:C:\ZUI
RAWPROGRAM:
rawprogram0.xml
PATCH:
patch0.xml
ACKRAWDATAEVERYNUMPACKETS:False
ACKRAWDATAEVERYNUMPACKETS:100
MAXPAYLOADSIZETOTARGETINBYTES:False
MAXPAYLOADSIZETOTARGETINBYTES:49152
DEVICETYPE:eMMC
PLATFORM:8x26
VALIDATIONMODE:0
RESETAFTERDOWNLOAD:False
MAXDIGESTTABLESIZE:8192
SWITCHTOFIREHOSETIMEOUT:30
RESETTIMEOUT:200
RESETDELAYTIME:2
FLATBUILDPATH:C:\
FLATBUILDFORCEOVERRIDE:True
QCNPATH:C:\Temp\00000000.qcn
QCNAUTOBACKUPRESTORE:False
SPCCODE:000000
ENABLEMULTISIM:False
Load ARG Configuration
Validating Download Configuration
Image Search Path: C:\ZUI
RAWPROGRAM file path: C:\ZUI\rawprogram0.xml
PATCH file path:C:\ZUI\patch0.xml
Programmer Path:C:\ZUI\prog_emmc_firehose_8996_ddr.elf
Process Index:0
Start Download
Program Path:C:\ZUI\prog_emmc_firehose_8996_ddr.elf
Binary build date: May 13 2015 @ 14:41:37
QSAHARASERVER CALLED LIKE THIS: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Qualcomm\QPST\bin\QSaharaServer.exe -p \\.\COM20 -s 13:C:\ZUI\prog_emmc_firehose_8996_ddr.elf 'Current working dir: C:\Users\vladi\AppData\Roaming\Qualcomm\QFIL
Sahara mappings:
2: amss.mbn
6: apps.mbn
8: dsp1.mbn
10: dbl.mbn
11: osbl.mbn
12: dsp2.mbn
16: efs1.mbn
17: efs2.mbn
20: efs3.mbn
21: sbl1.mbn
22: sbl2.mbn
23: rpm.mbn
25: tz.mbn
28: dsp3.mbn
29: acdb.mbn
30: wdt.mbn
31: mba.mbn
13: C:\ZUI\prog_emmc_firehose_8996_ddr.elf
17:01:24: ERROR: function: sahara_rx_data:194 Unable to read packet header. Only read 0 bytes.
17:01:24: ERROR: function: sahara_main:854 Sahara protocol error
17:01:24: ERROR: function: main:265 Uploading  Image using Sahara protocol failed
Download Fail:Sahara Fail:QSaharaServer Fail:Process fail
Finish Download
```

[Screenshot of QFIL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KC9Of.png)

The phone is in fastboot mode all the time. I tried to follow a dozen of howtos but no of them helped. I also used MiFlash, here are the error and the phone state:

[Fastboot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tu1Rj.png)

[MiFlash screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9jdn.png)

Comment: you need to switch device into EDL mode and install Qualcomm HS-USB QDLoader 9008 driver

Comment: @alecxs, I had an "failed to turn into EDL" error before that Sahara issue if it means anything. Thank you, I'll try

Comment: @alecxs, haven't I already done this? How do I distinguish normal and EDL modes?

Comment: something like `fastboot -i 0x2b4c oem ​​reboot-edl` you will see 9008 in device manager

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/software-hacking/guide-how-to-reboot-to-edl-fastboot-t3394292

Comment: https://youtu.be/QmT1rHqSINo

Comment: @alecxs, thanks for your help. But I already have it as a 9008 port. You can see it on the screenshots I provided. Correct me if i mistaken

Comment: i don't own this device but i don't think it can be in fastboot mode and EDL mode same time. sahara_rx_data:194 Unable to read packet header looks like the program did not receive data from phone (if rx mean receive / tx transmit)

Comment: is fastboot working or not? `fastboot getvar all`

Comment: according to this thread the issue can be a timeout. click the Download button right after entering EDL mode https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3624264

Answer (score 4):

See here how I solved this problem. Somehow Windows is blocking the flashing of the device, that's why the sahara error occurs.

https://superuser.com/questions/1538067/cannot-flash-qualcomm-with-stock-image-lenovo-tab-m10-tb-x605l-lte-android-8-o

Sorry for posting it as an answer, I don't have enough reputation yet to comment on questions. But, in fact, it's a working solution for the problem exactly as described, which - I hope - is anyway enough to qualify as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Error:-

Sahara server is failing : sahara protocal failed.

Ans:-

I have adjusted the cable connection and it work perfectly. ADB Cable was not connected properly.

another fix
just go to fastboot
hold power button as soon as mobile switches off , hold vol up and down button  to go to download state .
Now fastly press download button in QFIL tool it will start programming and download successfully . worked for me

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Are you sure your answer is intended for this question? OP didn't state the device was not detected, and the description doesn't suggest a connection issue (as the other answer confirms). If you indeed intended to answer this question, can you please provide a few more details to make that clear?