# Can't boot into recovery or fastboot and not going to EDL completely (Redmi Note 4)

Tags: rom-flashing, unbricking, rom, xiaomi, redmi-note-4

> **Please read the full text and help me if anything can solve my problem. Also I can't go to Mi help center due to this lockdown, so can you suggest ways the help center person would do to fix this issue?**

I have Redmi Note 4 (SD).
I flashed MIUI 11.0.6.0 port for mido (ROM discussed in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uqecqZcrO-Q&t=243s).)
It had many bugs so I was trying to flash back to stock ROM using Mi Flash Tool (old version).

**I was using linux for fastboot and adb commands and for Mi Flash Tool i was using win 7 in virtual box**

I selected **clean_all&lock.bat**
But after systerm image processing it gave me error

> error message said something about partition not been empty(sorry cant remember the exact error and log file also doesn't exist anymore)

Now my phone was on fastboot mode for atleast 5 hours so I used

```
fastboot reboot
```

via linux terminal.

But phone didn't boot and gave me black (empty screen)

I thought might be battery is low but when I connected it to charger nothing happened.

**I couldn't boot to recovery or fastboot mode (and can't do it now too)**.

I searched on internet more for help and found **about EDL mode.** 
I tried that but Virtual Machine wasn't loading the Qualcomm driver so **I installed windows 10** .

ALSO
I searched about the error on internet and found the solution to use latest mi flash tool.

So I tried with that. BUT I AM NOT SURE IF IT IS CONNECTED BY PROPER EDL MODE BECAUSE MI FLASH TOOL **INSTEAD OF SHOWING COMX AS DEVICE NAME, IT IS SHOWING MY INCOMPLETE FASTBOOT DEVICE NAME** .

I clicked to flash by selecting clean all&lock but it gave me this error

> The volume does not contain a recognized file system.Please make sure that all required file system drivers are loaded and that the volume is not corrupted.

**ALSO THE DEVICE IS SHOWN IN LATEST VERSION BUT NOT IN OLDER VERSION IN EDL MODE**

Then after many attempts to flash

Now it shows this

> $fastboot -s 34564c88 getvar product   2>&1  | findstr /r /c:"^product: *MSM8953"   || fastboot -s 34564c88 getvar product   2>&1  | findstr /r /c:"^product: *mido"   || echo Missmatching image and device

It was stuck at this for like 1000+ seconds.

I searched about it and tried this [solution](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_osMF9EubhI&t=159s). In this it tell to delete line 10 and 11 but in mine file it was present at 4 places so i deleted them all.

But then it got stuck at next command in **clean_all&lock.bat** file

> [9:39:38 PM  34564c88]:start process id 8956 name cmd
>   [9:39:38 PM  34564c88]:info1:$rem fastboot -s 34564c88 erase bk12 2>&1 
>   [9:39:38 PM  34564c88]:info1:$if not 0 == 0 exit /B 1 
>   [9:39:38 PM  34564c88]:info1:$fastboot -s 34564c88 oem device-info   2>&1  | findstr /r /c:"Device unlocked: true"   || echo Device oem locked

To give a try I deleted this line too but then it got stuck at next line.

---

ALSO TO ACCESS EDL WE NEED TO SHORT **JTAG PINS** BUT MY LAPTOP (WITH WIN 10) ACCEPTS IT WITHOUT DOING THAT

Comment: read [Mediatek](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=4064119) or [Qualcomm](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=4061651)

Comment: @alecxs I tried qfli tool and it gave me this error `Download Fail:Switch To EDL FailUnable to load DLL 'QMSL_MSVC10R.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)`

Comment: where have you posted the link because  using this [qualcomm](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=4061651) i tried qfli tool and it gave me this error `Download Fail:Switch To EDL FailUnable to load DLL 'QMSL_MSVC10R.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)`.      I am unable to boot to edl mode (i think!)

Comment: look at page 3 there you will find test point. after you managed this, there is a nice answer with link to pure [Linux Qualcomm USB flashing tool](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/224369)

Comment: i just switched from linux for just my phone to work. Can I run it in kali linux live usb or any other bootable usb for linux distro with persistence because virtual machine doesn't seem to accept  this device with port ( i tried with linux as main and win as virtual)?

Comment: you can run in any linux as long as persistence is large enough for compiling. if you have Laptop with Windows, use QPST instead

Comment: I have tried qpst and qfli but everytime i get some error like `fh loader failed` or `sahara failed`. Mi flash tool also gives me errror i.e. `cannot receive hello packets`. So I will be using Linux Method but I have one doubt **How would I know that I have successfully enabled edl mode?** because in windows device gets connected to **COM10** in non-EDL and **COM3** in EDL mode. So, **is there a similar way or linux will directly accept device in EDL mode only?**

Comment: you can see in device manager if it is named *Qualcomm HS-USB QDLoader* ***9008*** *(COM3)* then it is connected in EDL mode. for linux i don't know. you have a 30 second gap after connecting, after this Sahara fails with timeout https://android.stackexchange.com/q/219810

Comment: @alecxs is 10gb persistence enough? my rom size is 3.37gb

Comment: @alecxs I tried flashing **MIUI 9** using mi tool and it worked perfectly. Just want to clear something up! I selected **clean_all&lock.bat** while flashing but my bootloader is still unlocked. **So is it OK or it can cause any problem in future or it is imperfectly unlocked?**

Comment: it is recommended to keep bootloader unlocked, this way it is easier to rescue data (in case display is broken)

Comment: 1. What do you mean by display is broken?         2. But I selected clean_all$lock.bat so is it unlocked the correct way? or in edl mode that thing is not considered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Alecxs helped me with the solution so I am posting the solution that worked for me.

1. Install MIUI 9.6.8.0 fastboot ROM (it works with this only) and extract it to C drive.
2. Run MI flash tool and select the extracted folder.
3. Now boot the phone to EDL Mode and immediately click refresh and then click flash.
   Because if you are even 2-3 seconds late then process fails.
4. Wait for flashing to complete and then the phone will reboot.
   If it doesn't reboot then just check (press them a little bit) all the connectors on motherboards of phone (display, fingerprint and battery) and then connect to charger. Battery icon will appear and now you can power ON the phone.

**BOOTING TO EDL MODE**

> Don't remove battery. Not required.

To boot to EDL we need to short JTAG pins that are present on right side of fingerprint connector. (And not the 1st and 4th test points shown in many videos on internet).
And while shorting it insert the usb cable immediately. 
You will see red led light blinking.
Phone will be shown as COM4 (probably).

> For more information search google with **test points for Redmi Note 4**
>
> You will be forced to update to MIUI 11.0.2.0 because you will face
>   various bugs like
>
> - mi cloud won't sync
> - fingerprint won't work

**OTHER THINGS TO KEEP IN MIND**

1. If you decide to update to MIUI 11.0.2.0 then don't install **RedWolf** or ** OrangeFox** recovery because when you enable OTA updates in them and flash MIUI 11 rom you will get *ERROR 7 * message and and when you reboot you phone will **stuck on MI logo**.
2. When **stuck on MI logo** then don't try flashing rom again using Mi Flash Tool by booting to Fastboot mode (if you can boot to it) because you will get `System flashing error`.

**FIX FOR STUCK ON MI LOGO**

> Requirements
>
> - unlocked bootloader
> - adb and fastboot tools
> - fastboot extracted rom (can be MIUI 11)

If you are stuck there then don't worry. Try if you can boot to Fastboot Mode (Vol - with power key). **If not then try recovery mode or repeat EDL method.** *If yes then read ahead.*

If you can then install adb and fastboot tools in your PC. And paste all images folder files of MIUI 11 fastboot rom to adb folder.
Now type the following:

Check if phone is accepted by

```
fastboot devices
```

Now flash system.img by

```
fastboot flash system system.img
```

After completion flash boot.img by

```
fastboot flash boot boot.img
```

After completion flash recovery.img

```
fastboot flash recovery recovery.img
```

After completion flash cache.img

```
fastboot flash cache cache.img
```

> If you want to completely erase user data and make the device a newly
>   bought then type
>
> ```
> fastboot erase userdata
> ```
>
> After completion type
>
> ```
> fastboot flash userdata userdata.img
> ```

**Flashing is completed**

Now just type `fastboot reboot`. Phone will boot properly now.

> If you are using MIUI 9 or 10 rom to fix stuck on mi logo then when
>   the flashing is done you will face numerous bugs in rom like
>
> - mi cloud won't sync
> - fingerprint won't work properly