# What is the difference between fastboot command flashing and flashing using a flash tool(like mi flash tool flashing)?

Tags: fastboot, xiaomi, miui, stock-rom, flashtool

**BACKGROUND**

Xiaomi has its own Mi Flash Tool in which we select the .bat and flash.

But if we use fastboot commands then we only need system.img, boot.img, recovery.img, cache.img and userdata.img

So I checked .bat files using notepad++ and they contain commands for various other files too like modem etc that are present in images folder.

But phone gets booted perfectly with both methods!

**QUESTIONS**

1. Are those other files not important?
2. How the fastboot mode that uses less files work too?
3. Does those images only flash the other files? Because in [tutorial](https://in.c.mi.com/thread-334-1-0.html) the person said to copy all files of images folder to adb folder.

Comment: it's not true what they say, various other partitions like *modem* etc are important. just because you flashed only *boot system vendor* ... - that doesn't mean your device will work without - all partitions (erase them you will see). afaik *'fastboot flash'* only works for **unlocked** bootloader. MIFlash not only run *fastboot.exe*, it can flash via *Qualcomm HS-USB QDLoader 9008* with *fh_loader.exe*, too

Comment: @beeshyams see this [post](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/224654/302181). My phone was hard bricked. I got it fixed and when I flashed OrangeFox recovery and enabled OTA and flashed full MIUI 11 rom again (as the recovery says so that it can detect OTA in future) but it gave me error 7. And when I turned it on it got stuck on Mi logo. Mi flash tool gavee system flashing error so I flashed using fastboot commands. And my bootloader is unlocked.

Comment: @beeshyams so are these critical partition important?  Will not flashing them cause any errors because my phone is working fine now except one problem that I can't update system launcher app of MI (whenever I install an APK of its new version from apkmirror it gets installed but  when I add any widget or any new app is added then it gives me error saying **system launcher has stopped**.

Comment: @beeshyams how to flash those critical partitions?

Comment: @alecxs hi, so I should flash them?... How?.... Should I take a backup or those partitions won't delete all data?

Comment: no. because firmware/baseband isn't changed very frequently, i doubt there is a difference between MIUI 9 and MIUI 11. but can be flashed from fastboot (*'fastboot flashing unlock_critical*' may required)

Comment: @alecxs will those partitions be flashed if I use re-download the update package from updater app and install that from updater app only?

Comment: @alecxs yeah and so far I haven't faced any problems except that system launcher stopping one. Is there fix for that? Because it's really not possible to arrange icons with the old version.

Comment: idk but guess yes. i assume it depends on update package. it usually make some checks

Comment: @alecxs ok thanks I will try it.

Comment: @alecxs my doubt is solved. Please post your views/comments as answer to my question.

Comment: @alecxs [this](https://pastebin.com/xvDfUqQ7) is the error message I see when any widget or new app is added .

Comment: i don't understand java. try another [launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher) if the problem remains it is not launcher error