# unable to flash rom in edl mode using linux qdl or even qfil or miflash. what could be the error?

Tags: rom-flashing, flashtool

i have a redmi note 3 snapdragon variant.
i was using it casually and i pulled its back cover and wassss in deep thoughts when i accidentaly or stupidly removed the battery flap when phone was on. i put thhe battery back it didnt turn on and i plugged the charger it gave red blinking light no screen on. so it was stuck no change even after many methods.

i plugged it in windows laptop and was surprised it recognized as in edl mode(although not instantly learned becuase i am not much knowledgeable).

so after trying many miflash or qfil or and many tricks for them given by xda, i couldnt flash the rom, so many sahara errors or hello packet errors.
i tried the linux method and it still gave hello packet error on linux using qdl tool.

so i am not sure if emmc is damaged or its is locked. in one xda thread one guy said it could be emmc read or write locked. any tips.

update; the error or log i recieve:
HELLO version: 0x2 compatible: 0x1 max_len: 1024 mode: 0
READ image: 13 offset: 0x0 length: 0x34
END OF IMAGE image: 13 status: 20
received non-successful result

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sahara fail while trying to flash a rom into my phone](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/219810/sahara-fail-while-trying-to-flash-a-rom-into-my-phone)

Comment: nope, i am using the linux method given in that answer. but i am getting the error not mentioned there.

Comment: after booting in EDL emergency download mode there is a ~ 2 seconds timeout as stated in comments

Comment: yeah but my device is stuck in edl mode. no matter what. doesnt matter if its 30 or hour

Comment: that's probably too long try start flashing immediately when connecting usb cable. also check `lsusb` if device is detected in 9008 mode

Comment: if you think device is read-only try to just read something with edl.py https://android.stackexchange.com/q/226838

Comment: can u explain more about lsusb

Comment: press ctrl + alt + T and type `lsusb` in terminal